# Get the Top 5 users in each month for the last three months Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have this query

```
Post.objects.filter(issued_at__isnull=False, issued_at__gte=three_months_ago).annotate(
month=TruncMonth('issued_at'))[:5].values('month').annotate(num_of_posts=Sum('number_of_posts')).values(
'month', 'user__name', 'num_of_posts').order_by('-num_of_posts')[:15]
```

All I need right now is getting only the top 5 users of each month (so in total 15 users are going to be returned). As you can see I tried to slice 5 after the annotate but a
`AssertionError: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.` error rises. Also, I tried slicing 15 users but that didn't work because the wrong users are being returned.

Comment: * Please add your Model structure and relations.
* What do you mean by `Top` user?

Comment: @tarasinf by top I mean the highest users in the number of creation of the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to make three queries:

```
top_month_1 = Post.objects.filter(
    issued_at__gte=months_ago_1,
).values(
    'user',
).annotate(
    posts_created=Count('user'),
).order_by('-posts_created')[:5]

top_month_2 = ...

top_month_3 = ...
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that before, I am going to accept this answer until a more convenient one comes

Answer (score 0):

window functions might come handy here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions

Comment: I checked it but it didn't work unfortunately, or maybe I didn't figure out how to use them correctly.